Is EXIF timestamp affected by write buffering?
In general, if you capture an image at time X, but the camera is write buffering after a long continuous shot burst, when the image is written to card at time X + y, will the EXIF values for Date Time Original and Sub-second Time Original reflect X or X + y?
If anyone knows any specifics around the behaviour of modern DSLRs and/or Mirrorless cameras in this regard, that would be interesting to know too.

This is possibly already answered in this question.  The accepted answer says the events that trigger the timestamp are unspecified, and to do an experiment by pointing your camera at clock, and reconciling the EXIF value with the image, just so you can know what your camera does.  Also see the comment about the PDF on this answer, which has some interesting info.

Thanks @PeterM - those links are very useful. It always amazes me how loosely specific metadata standards are, especially for things which might reasonably be taken as having a precise meaning!

I think root issue is that it would be impossible to get all manufacturers to comply with a strict standard of metadata.  It would mean all cameras would have to certified to a certain metadata standard, and anything related to certification would be very expensive.  Having a looser standard makes for a cheaper product.

Buying a camera intended for creative photography and expecting it to provide  precision of a lab grade scientific instrument is a bit of an unrealistic expectation.

@MichaelC you seem to have read more into my question than was written and at the same time failed to provide any additional useful insights. Thanks.

Does this answer your question? When is each of these EXIF date & time variables created, and in what circumstances do they change?
